# Call C code with cython and cython-code from c

Tags: python, cython

this is my first question here. Up to now I got a lot of answers by other questions, but now there is no more answer.

The aim of my work is to work with a developed stack of a communication-module (get as .so), which is written in C. I want to combine it with python (cython), because all other software is already written so. After creating and testing the direction from cython to c, I worked the last days for direction from c to cython [like here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c). The stack made an event-driffen call of a function in a c-function and I want to integrate a call of a cython function for logging and further data-handling. But after two days I hang up. It doesn't work, because the initmodulename-functioncall in the c-function raised an error.
So I developed the following minimal example to get it work, cython and c in both directions. It is an extended example to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026523/undefined-symbol-error-importing-cython-module).

I have 3 files, **the main.c**

```c
#include <python3.4/Python.h>
#include "caller.h"
int main() {
Py_Initialize();
initcaller();
call_quack();
Py_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

the **caller.pyx**

```py
from quacker import quack

cdef public void call_quack():
    quack()

def run():
    cdef extern from "main.c":
        int main()
    main()
```

and the **quacker.py**

```py
def quack():
    print("Quack!")
```

The target is to import caller, start run() as function, which call the c-function and call call_quack() back.

To compile I use (this comes from the main project):

```
CC="gcc -std=c99" CFLAGS="-DCPLB_VENDOR_EAG_TARGETSYSTEM_SHLIBSIEC104_ARM_LINUX -O2 -fPIC"  IFLAGS="-I/usr/include/python3.4 -lpython3.4"  python3.4 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

with the setup.py

```py
 # setup.py file
 import sys
 import os
 import shutil
 from distutils.core import setup
 from distutils.extension import Extension
 from Cython.Distutils import build_ext


setup(
cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
ext_modules = [
    Extension("caller", 
              sources=["caller.pyx",
                       ],
              include_dirs=["/usr/include//python3.4"],
              extra_compile_args=["-fopenmp", "-O3"],
              extra_link_args=["-DSOME_DEFINE_OPT", 
                               "-L./some/extra/dependency/dir/"]
         )
    ]
    )
```

There is no error during compilation and linking.
But when I start python3.4 and import caller I get the following error

```
ImportError: /home/rvk/software/test/caller.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: initcaller
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? I never read any example about usind cython and c in both directions! Is it possible?

I already checked the cythonized c-File (caller.c) - there is a initcaller-method, but only for PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3?!

Thanks a lot in advance

**Edit**

I got it work by remove the PyInitialze, initcaller and PyFinalize - function calls in the **main.c**. Maybe this is related to the issue, that I already declared the main.c in the pyx, so its part of the compiled library?! Don't know where the leak is concerning [cython user guide](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c)

The new main.c:

```c
#include <python3.4/Python.h>
#include "caller.h"
int main() {
call_quack();
return 0;
}
```

I also integrated it in the main-project. Here the challenge was, that the c-function, which should call the function in the cython-file, is a callback-c-function, so it is necessary to define the function in the cython file **with gil**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `caller.pyx` there is

```
def run():
    cdef extern from "main.c":
        int main()
    main()
```

that causes trouble by including `main.c`, that in turn includes `caller.h` which is something unexpected by the code generated by cython. Furthermore, calling that `main()` defined in `main.c` might cause trouble when in happens in python interpreter. So `cdef extern from "main.c":` should be removed.

In case of python 3.x, it is like `PyInit_modulename()`, not `initmodule()`

```
int main() 
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyInit_caller();
    call_quack();
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Yes, I saw this in the cythonized file, but it does not work - compilation error raised. Do you know why?

caller.c:915:16: error: conflicting types for ‘PyInit_caller’
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_caller(void); /*proto*/

Comment: @J.Werner I did not notice that `cdef extern from "main.c"` initially, only that `initcaller();` / `PyInit_modulename()` related problem. I hope my answer is now more useful.

Comment: @ J.J. Hakala If I a remove the $cdef extern from "main.c", than I got the error, that main.c is undeclared.  I found a workarround to work in both directions, see edit of the question. I don't know why its not like in the [cython user guide](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c)