# Importing any module in cython file gives undefined symbol error

Tags: python, numpy, cython

When I use *any* import statement within modules I compile with cython, I receive the following error on importing the modules (see full code below):

```
ImportError: /.../hw.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: __intel_sse2_strchr
```

Everything works fine on my own machine, but I get this error when trying to recompile and run my scripts on an external high-performance computer.

Googling I saw similar errors pop up in several places, but in these discussions the problem is either related to an error in the own code, rather than an imported module (e.g. [Undefined symbol error importing Cython module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026523/undefined-symbol-error-importing-cython-module)) or something goes wrong at building cython or compile time (e.g. [Can cython be compiled with icc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904377/can-cython-be-compiled-with-icc)). I don't see how to apply these to my case.

From reading other discussions, I suspected the problem was in the formulation of my `setup.py`, but I really don't know much about that - on my own system the standard examples simply worked. I tried adding numpy to the setup (see `setup2.py` below), but that didn't solve the problem - I get the same error on `import hw`.

**Full example**

hw.pyx:

```
import numpy  # without this line, the example works fine 

cpdef testfun():
    print("Hello world!")
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize('hw.pyx'),
)
```

setup2.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize('hw.pyx'),
    include_dirs = [np.get_include()]  # -> including this doesn't make a difference
)
```

**System info**

The external system runs python 3.5.2. I run my code within a virtualenv, where I have Cython 0.28.1. I tried both numpy 1.13.0 and 1.14.2. For the virtuel environment in this example, I did not install any other packages (probably not related to my problem, but `pip freeze` also lists `UNKNOWN==0.0.0`)

[**IMPORTANT EDIT**]

I received the error for numpy (and since I had struggled before with `cdef np.ndarray` I figured that was the problem) - but actually it is *any* import statement that causes the error - numpy just happened to be the first module that was imported. Still no clue how to resolve this though.

Comment: It looks as if you would compile with intel compiler, but don’t provide intel runtime libraries to the linker. Switch to gcc or provide the needed runtime libraries

Comment: Thanks, using `CC=gcc python setup.py build_ext --inplace` gives a working module! Is there a speed advantage in using the intel compiler? How can I find out what the needed runtime libraries are, and how would I make those available?

Comment: Ah I probably should use a different Python distribution that is also available: `python/3.5.2-intel-u2`. If I try this, I get a different undefined symbol error on import: `undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard`

Comment: There seems to be a problem with loading the intel Python and the `mpi` module at the same time, whereas I need the `mpi` module as well. So I will just go with the `gcc` compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I used the Intel compiler without running the Intel Python distribution, or otherwise providing the Intel runtime libraries.

Thanks to @ead, I resolved the problem by switching to GCC using:

```
CC=gcc python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```